# Using Datepicker via Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, datepicker, calendar, ecmascript-6, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a page, where I have start date and end date. once start date is selected, the end date will automatically gray out all dates 30 days after the start date. I have defined the data-range-max-days="30" in my html markup.

My first issue is that when I submit the form, the page reloads. However even though it shows the start date in the field, the end date now does not have that 30 day constraint and I can select any date, which is not what I want it to do.

MY First take of the code is this:

```
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker';

    import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css';

    export default class {
      constructor(el) {

        $(el).datetimepicker({
          icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
            clear: "fa fa-refresh"
          }, // use font awesome icons cause I'm vain
          useCurrent: false, // don't default to current datetime
          ignoreReadonly: true,
          showClear: true
        });

        if($(el).hasClass('startDate')) {
            this.listen();
        }
      }

      listen() {
        $('.startDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {

          $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
          $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(false);
          $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').showClear(true);

          if(e.date) {
            var addDays = $('.endDate').data('rangeMaxDays');
            if(addDays > 0) {

              var currentDate = new Date();
              var maxDate = new Date(e.date);
              maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + addDays);

              var maxDateStr = (maxDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' + maxDate.getDate() + '-' + maxDate.getFullYear() + ' 11:59 PM';

              if(currentDate > maxDate) {
                $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').showClear(false);
                $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(maxDateStr);
              }

              // Add days to limit the max selectable date
              $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(maxDateStr);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

My second take in trying to break up the functionality is resulting in errors where methods such as clear() etc are not being recognized once dp.change is taken out the picture.

```
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css';

export default class {
  constructor(el) {

    $(el).datetimepicker({
      icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
        clear: "fa fa-refresh"
      }, // use font awesome icons cause I'm vain
      useCurrent: false, // don't default to current datetime
      ignoreReadonly: true,
      showClear: true
    });

    if($(el).hasClass('startDate')) {
        this.listen();
    }
  $('.startDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      this.listen();
  });
  }



  listen() {
 // $('.startDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {

      $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').clear();
      $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(false);
      $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').showClear(true);

      if(e.date) {
        var addDays = $('.endDate').data('rangeMaxDays');
        if(addDays > 0) {

          var currentDate = new Date();
          var maxDate = new Date(e.date);
          maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + addDays);

          var maxDateStr = (maxDate.getMonth()+1) + '-' + maxDate.getDate() + '-' + maxDate.getFullYear() + ' 11:59 PM';

          if(currentDate > maxDate) {
            $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').showClear(false);
            $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(maxDateStr);
          }

          // Add days to limit the max selectable date
          $('.endDate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(maxDateStr);
        }
      }
  // });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.
Use bootstrapper 3 dp.show method to detect input and from there perform a recalculation.